# Capping a Side Spray Opening on a Moen Faucet

Tags: faucet, dishwasher, hose, connectors

I am setting up a portable dishwasher (an 18-inch GE portable dishwasher). Similar to [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/177528/side-spray-and-a-portable-dishwasher) from last year, I am planning to connect the dishwasher to a kitchen faucet with a side spray.

According to GE, "A sink spray attachment hose can burst if it is installed on the same faucet as your dishwasher. We suggest that you disconnect the sink spray attachment, if your sink has one, and place a cap over the opening."

So I've been trying to figure out how to cap the opening. I have a [Moen Adler one-handle kitchen faucet](https://www.moen.com/products/Adler/Adler_Spot_resist_stainless_onehandle_kitchen_faucet/87202SRS).

[image: Moen Faucet]

I spoke with a representative from Moen and they claim that they don't create a cap/plug for this model. (They have a side spray plug service kit for other faucets.)

**Does anyone know if there are any other options to cap the opening?** I am looking for some way to remove the spray hose and block the flow of water that would normally go to the spray hose. As you can see in the diagrams below, the opening doesn’t appear to be a standard shape with a set diameter.

Here is a diagram of the spray:

[image: Moen Spray Diagram]

Here are diagrams illustrating how to connect the spray to the faucet:

[image: Moen Spray Hose Installation Diagram]

[image: Moen Spray Hose Installation Diagram]

For your reference, the specifications for the faucet can be found [here](https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/19/19073f82-66cd-4023-b86a-2fa394a537dc.pdf), the parts list [here](https://www.moen.com/shared/docs/exploded-parts-views/87202pt.pdf), and the installation guide [here](https://www.moen.com/shared/docs/exploded-parts-views/87202pt.pdf).

I would greatly appreciate any guidance that you could share.

Thank you.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Moen-22897-Cover-Stainless-Steel/dp/B01M7YLGVD

Comment: You are probably going to need a different faucet.

Comment: As the person that asked the referenced question, the bottom line isn't the side spray, it's the diverter that's the concern.  My faucet's diverter was a separate piece on the bottom that I removed to disconnect the side spray.  Looks like your faucet has the diverter integrated into it.  I think I'd go along with @Alaska Man and get a new faucet.

Comment: Why would the line burst? Where are you getting the water from I have had many side sprays until pull out nozzles became popular and I always T my hot to the dishwasher how is that doing to have any affect on the faucet? Am I missing something?

Comment: Duston, Alaska Man, Kris: Thank you for your comments! Very helpful. I've been coming to the same conclusion.

Comment: @EdBeal I was also wondering if I really need to do this. My understanding is that the spray hose and faucet are integrated. Here's the explanation from GE: "When the sink faucet is turned on to furnish water to the portable dishwasher, it is also putting the same pressure on the spray hose at the sink. These spray hoses are not designed for constant water pressure for the length of a wash cycle. After a while the hose will begin to leak at the joints or split and flood."

Comment: Ok is your faucet being directly connected to the dishwasher like a portable connection ? This is what they are talking about if you tap your plumbing supply the faucet is in the off position and you don’t need to worry, I will make this an answer now that I understand the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to disconnect the spray wand if you have a portable connection to the faucet nozzle with the faucet in the on position.
If you connect to the plumbing so the faucet is in the off position you do not need to remove your sprayer.

Sorry I did not catch that sooner but connecting prior to the faucet it self is the same as every other point on the plumbing system. At the nozzle faucet on 100% hot I can see the sprayer not being rated for that combination of pressure and heat.  If you add an adapter to your hot line for the quick disconnect that would be the way around having to disconnect the sprayer.